# Ehcache vs In-memory db vs NoSql for read/write heavy workload

Tags: java, database, ehcache, nosql

I need to implement Session management for my company, we were using RDBMS till now but the latency is too high as the latency for session data should be very low.

So I thought of researching it out on web and found out these three options:

- Ehcache + Terracota
- In Memory DB (Timesten and others)
- NoSQL (Aerospike, Couchbase )

Now I am starting to try these solutions out, but would like to get 2 cents from the experienced ones. The workload pattern would be 50/50 read/write and needs cluster for HA.

We need high throughput, low latency and eventual consistency.

As per what I have searched it seems like NoSQL is good fit for this scenario but would like to hear more on this.

Which of these options is best suited for such workloads?

Answer (score 3):

Ad Business is one of the largest industry which uses session management. And I have seen almost all of them consider NoSQL based solution.

Since the prime requirement for Ad Business is display ads with least latency they usually tend to store data In-Memory for bringing down the latency. But that comes at cost.

Since you have already mentioned Aerospike, It is optimised for SSD and thus you can have sub millisecond level latency achieved by storing data on SSD as well. And this product is recently being open sourced.

There are other options like Redis, mentioned in above comment but Aerospike does provides benefits like Cross Data Center Replication for HA purpose and auto sharding. It is very easy to setup and get running with minimal configuration.

So I would vote for NoSQL looking at your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft offers in ASP.NET and their PaaS, Azure, to use Redis as a session store. I suppose they know why they chose to support this specific NoSQL DB, so you might want to have a look into it.

Redis is in memory key value store and offers time bound inserts (data can be deleted automatically by redis after some time). Additionally you can also deploy it on multiple machines to reach a better performance or higher availability.